# expl3: \tl_put_right:Nx chokes on \{

Tags: expansion, expl3

I am trying to compose a command into a token list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \tl_new:N \__a
  \tl_new:N \__b
  \tl_new:N \__c
  \tl_set:Nn \__a { test }
  \tl_set:Nn \__b { \{ }  % works with { brace } but not with { \{ }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \__c { \exp_not:N \m { \__a } { \__b } }
  \tl_show:N \__c % expected result: \m{test}{\{}
  \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Everything worked fine, but when I have a `\{` token, the whole thing breaks. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: `\{` doesn't survive `\edef`, so it can't appear where full expansion is made. In LaTeX3 (when fully available) it will.

Comment: Hmm. Any other idea? Could I test for \{ in advance and replace it by something different that - in the end,  when \m renders - creates a curly brace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commands such as `\{` are to be used with care because they are defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`. The expansion of `\{` is

```
\x@protect \{\protect \{
```

and this is a sure sign that using it in an `x` argument is doomed to failure.

You could redefine

```
\protected\def\{{\ifmmode \lbrace \else \textbraceleft \fi}
```

and it would work; in `xparse` parlance it would be

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \{ { }
 {
  \mode_if_math:TF { \lbrace } { \textbraceleft }
 }
```

and this would survive `x` expansion. One of the tasks waiting the LaTeX3 team is to redefine all such commands with ‘\protected’ macros instead of `\DeclareRobustCommand`. The reason is that `\protected` wasn't available when LaTeX2e was developed: it's one of the e-TeX extensions.

It would be a *huge* task to redefine all robust commands (`\textbraceleft` would need a rather different treatment). You can safely expand one level only, but probably you should take a different approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \tl_new:N \__my_a_tl
  \tl_new:N \__my_b_tl
  \tl_new:N \__my_c_tl
  \tl_set:Nn \__my_a_tl { test }
  \tl_set:Nn \__my_b_tl { \{ }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \__my_c_tl
   {
    \exp_not:N \m { \exp_not:V \__my_a_tl } { \exp_not:V \__my_b_tl }
   }
  \tl_show:N \__my_c_tl % expected result: \m{test}{\{}
  \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Output on terminal:

```
> \__my_c_tl=macro:
->\m {test}{\{}.
```

Comment: Wow, cool. `\exp_not:V` does the trick. I tried so many times with `\exp_not:N` and was so very close.

Comment: @user41056 It means: get the value of the following variable and pass the result like it was `\exp_not:n { <value> }`